# Android communicate custom View and DialogFragment with listener

Tags: android, interface, communication, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to create a communication between a custom View and a DialogFragment with an interface/callback.

**Custom View:**

```
public MyDraw extends View implements ColorPickerListener
{
   public MyDraw(Context context)
   {
      super(context);

     // ...

     MyDialogFragment.setColorPickerListener(this);
   }


   @Override
   public void onColorChanged(int color)
   {
      // ...
   }
}
```

**DialogFragment**

```
public MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
   public interface ColorPickerListener
   {
      public void onColorChanged(int color);
   }

   ColorPickerListener colorPickerListener;    

   public static void setColorPickerListener(ColorPickerListener listener)
   {
      colorPickerListener = listener;
   }

   // ....       

   private void colorSelected(int color)
   {
      colorPickerListener.onColorChanged(color);
   }
}
```

This is working, but I'm not sure if this is Ok. I am afraid of memory leaks, because I am referencing a static method from View to the dialog fragment.

Is there any alternative solution, like getting the activity, the instance or casting to something?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call the static `setColorPickerListener` method. You can find your `DialogFragment` instance using `findFragmentByTag` method and then simply call your `setColorPickerListener` (non-static method).

```
public void showPickerDialog() {
   DialogFragment newFragment = new PickerFragment();

    newFragment.show(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialogfrag1");
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

      // getting the fragment 
   PickerFragment df1 = (PickerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialogfrag1");
    if (df1 != null)    {
   df1.registerListener(this);
    }
}
```